# Why Path-convergence criterion Requirement 6 is necessary?

Tags: compilers

The path-convergence criterion states that there should be a φ-function for variable
a at node z of the flow graph exactly when all of the following are true:

1. There is a block x containing a definition of a,
2. There is a block y (y $\neq$ x) containing a definition of a,
3. There is a nonempty path $P_{xz}$ of edges from x to z,
4. There is a nonempty path $P_{yz}$ of edges from y to z,
5. Paths $P_{xz}$ and $P_{yz}$ do not have any node in common other than z, and
6. The node z does not appear within both $P_{xz}$ and $P_{yz}$ prior to the end, though
   it may appear in one or the other.

Why the phrase “though it may appear in one or the other” in the last statement is necessary?